# Force Jenkins to run build on a different node in a label everytime?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project setup that runs on the MISC label everytime it builds, and it had been working great.

However, I've encountered a problem where, if the previous build on one machine fails, it can cause further builds on that machine to fail as well. It would be fine on another slave.

We will like the job to run on a different node in the label, if possible, in case this happens again in the future.

Thanks,

Comment: it feels like your real problem is that subsequent builds on the same slave fail after it fails once. to answer your question, i doubt that's possible, but hopefully if someone knows they weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems. My solution is to take the node offline if certain types of errors happen.

I'm using this plugin to run a groovy script after every build ttps://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin

My script looks like this

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.slaves.OfflineCause

// this script is designed to be called by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin

if (BUILD_RESULT == "FAILURE") {
  println("The job failed. The build failure cause will be checked.")
  job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME)
  build = job.getBuildByNumber(BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger())
  def buildLog = build.log

  if (buildLog.contains("something indicating an unrecoverable error")) {
      Node buildNode = build.getBuiltOn();

      // Never set master offline
      if (Hudson.getInstance() != buildNode) {
        println("This is fatal. The node ${NODE_NAME} is being taken offline.")
        buildNode.toComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(true, OfflineCause.create(new OfflineMessage()));
      } else {
        println("The error is marked to take the node offline, but the node is not being taken offline because it is the master")
      }
  }
}

class OfflineMessage extends org.jvnet.localizer.Localizable {
  def message
  OfflineMessage() {
    super(null, null, [])
    def timestr = new Date().format("HH:mm dd/MM/yy z", TimeZone.getDefault())
    this.message = "This node was taken offline because of a failed job at " + timestr
  }
  String toString() {
    this.message
  }
  String toString(java.util.Locale l) {
    toString()
  }
}
```